# Is there a way to create searchable or coloured tags for nodes on d3 force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, jekyll, d3-force-directed

I'm working on a force directed graph for a university project. We have to create a 'research archive' that presents all our research material – I've started mine here as a digital garden using Maxime Vaillancourt's Jekyll digital garden template (which uses d3). You can view it [here](https://stalwart-starlight-4da401.netlify.app/).

Part of the reason I started with this was I was using obsidian for a while, but wanted a) it in a website format, c) something I could easily share with my tutors etc, and c) more customisable options than obsidian). Maybe it's a bit of an obsidian hang-up, but I really want to be able to add 'tags' to entry, e.g. by theme, or by entry type (so different tags for images, journal articles, primary research, etc). I'm struggling to find answers relating to this, and think maybe I'm too stuck on the idea of 'tags' and not thinking through other ways people might be expressing/phrasing something which achieves the same thing.

Ideally, I'd like these to be a toggleable feature, e.g. click a sidebar button to view all entries tagged with XYZ.

However, I was also thinking it could work through different styled/coloured lines that show connections by tag (so an entry would have, say, bold black lines to other entries they're linked to; a dashed grey line to ones that are also tagged with 'photograph'; a dotted blue ones to ones that are also tagged with 'health'; etc). Or, giving each entry only one tag, and that tag denoting the colour of the node.

The reason I am keen on this, is I would like to be able to show different 'levels' of connections, but at the moment am struggling with the 'difinitiveness' of the single line. I know for some people who use Obsidian as a zettelkasten tool they're into using links effectively as tags (e.g. having a list of 'tags' at the bottom which are in effect links), but a) I don't think this really works in the same way, and b) it requires creating full entries for themes or tags that might not naturally need one (going back to the photograph example - this work around would require creating a separate .md file titled 'photograph' which people would be able to navigate to, which would either mean I'd have to write some forced entry for this, or people would inevitably stumble on lots of dead pages.

I'm not expecting someone to come and fix my problem, but more ideas on what sort of features could work. I am self taught at a lot of this stuff, and so in particular often struggle with knowing what it is I am looking for/asking for – like I lack the language, even though I'm often able to actually work out how to do things once I've got on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is ever stuck in a similar position –

I was managing to do a lot of the things I wanted on fiddles, but not via the template above. For some reason, I could get it to there being no errors/problems in the console log, but it just wouldn't actually 'work' (ie, there was a search bar, but typing into it wasn't performing the right functions, etc). I'm sure a more technologically capable person could work out what was the clash between the template and my edits that was causing this. But, after lots of trying, I stumbled upon https://github.com/jackyzha0/quartz – which so far already has a lot of things I wanted semi built in, and so far seems a bit more receptive to edits in this way.